# Truffle installation -- naming conflicts on Windows

Tags: truffle, dapps, dapp-development, windows, installation

Wanted to follow this [tutorial](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/create-and-deploy-a-defi-app/) to deploy a Defi app.
 I use windows and wanted to follow this

```
mkdir your-project-name # I know its making a directory
cd your-project-name # Iknow I'm entering that directory
truffle init # Did'nt understand this
```

And tried to run it and got this error

```
truffle : The term 'truffle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle init
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (truffle:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I understand cryptic and Defi to an extent but a real rookie in coding.
What to do?

Comment: Did you install truffle?

Comment: Yes I did this https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are reading uses truffle.

To [install](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/installation.html) truffle:

```
npm install -g truffle
```

Note the **[Recommendations for Windows](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/installation.html#recommendations-for-windows)**:

> If you're running Truffle on Windows, you may encounter some naming conflicts that could prevent Truffle from executing properly.

> When using the Command Prompt on Windows, the default configuration file name can cause a conflict with the truffle executable, and so you may not be able to run Truffle commands properly on existing projects.

> Any of the following solutions will remedy this issue:

> - Call the executable file explicitly using its .cmd extension (truffle.cmd compile)
> - Edit the system PATHEXT environment variable and remove .JS; from the list of executable extensions
> - Rename truffle.js to something else (truffle-config.js)
> - Use Windows PowerShell or Git BASH, as these shells do not have this conflict.

https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#resolving-naming-conflicts-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for this, but I did use windows power shell

Answer (score 0):

check to see if truffle is properly installed with

```
npm list -g
```

also check your environment variables.

```
refreshenv
```

is also good to try if you were expecting something to show but didn't

If it's still not working, you may want to make sure you are in an administrator powershell.